# How to manage two method calls to a DAO from a service layer in single transaction in Spring MVC and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

In the service layer class in a method i'm calling a delete method and an insert method of a DAO layer as follows.

Service class:

```
 @Service("workflowService")
    @Transactional
    public class WorkFlowServiceImpl implements WorkFlowService {
    @Autowired
    WorkFlowDao workFlowDao;
        public String deleteSelectedTask(String strWorkFlowName, int intIndex) {
                JSONObject res = new JSONObject();
                try{
                    List<WorkflowPermission> listWorkflowPermission = workFlowDao.getWorkFlowPermissionByName(strWorkFlowName);
                    listWorkflowPermission.remove(intIndex-1);
                    boolean flag = workFlowDao.deleteWorkFlowPermissionByName(strWorkFlowName);
                    for(int i =0;i<listWorkflowPermission.size();i++){
                        listWorkflowPermission.get(i).setOrderNo(i+1);
                        flag = workFlowDao.createWorkFlowPermission(listWorkflowPermission.get(i));
                    }
                    if(flag==true){
                        res.put("status", "Success");
                        res.put("message", "Task Deleted Successfully");
                    }else{
                        res.put("status", "Fail");
                        res.put("message", "Cannot Delete Task");
                    }
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error(e);
                }
                return res.toString();  
            }
    }
```

Here first i'm getting a list from DAO and deleting the entries on that table and using the for loop i'm inserting as new record by changing the order by calling `setOrderNO`.

DAO class:

```
 @Repository("workflowDao")
    public class WorkFlowDaoImpl implements WorkFlowDao {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private Session session;
    @Override
        public boolean deleteWorkFlowPermissionByName(String strWorkFlowName) {
            try{
                session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
                SQLQuery sqlQuery= session.createSQLQuery("DELETE FROM UPS_ESC_WTL WHERE workflow_name='"+strWorkFlowName+"'");
                sqlQuery.executeUpdate();
                session.flush();
                return true;
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }

    public boolean createWorkFlowPermission(
                WorkflowPermission workFlowPermission) {
            boolean blStatus = false;
            try {
                session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
                session.saveOrUpdate(workFlowPermission);
                session.flush();
                blStatus = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(e);
                throw new DataAccessException();
            }
            return blStatus;
        }
    }
```

While debugging the code i'm getting the list form database and all records from the table gets deleted. While iterating over the list its properly going through the method of inserting the record. But its not reflecting in the db.
I want to handle transaction with rollback for this and to insert the records to db. Also i have added the `HibernateTransactionManager` in applicationContext.xml

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
```

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: For starters remove the `flush`es from the repository as well as the `try/catch` blocks (those can and will interfere with proper tx management). Also your Dao is flawed don't store the `Session` in an instance variable (try to imagine what happens if 5 calls to the same method are made at once!). Add your `SessionFactory` configuration to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Add the annotation @Transactional to all methods you need to share the same DB transaction, then the rollback would be applied to all operations.

Example

```
public class ServiceFirstImpl

@Autowired
FirstDao firstDao;

@Autowired
SecondDao secondDao;


@Transactional
public void mixActions(){
    firstDao.delete();
    secondDao.create();
}
```

Comment: You don't need to annotate the repository with `@Transactional` it will already participate in the transaction for the service without that.

Answer (score 0):

One of your problem is on deleteWorkFlowPermissionByName method

```
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Becouse the Spring Transaction will do an rollback if the method throw an RuntimeException or one declared exception.
Now your code will not trigger an rollback if there are an exception in deleteWorkFlowPermissionByName method.

It is enough to have @Transactional on the class in your case. Write to the method unless you want to have different transaction type to some methods.